# Opposite operation to Assembly Load(byte[] rawAssembly)

Tags: c#, .net

I notice that there is a method of `System.Reflection.Assembly`, which is `Assembly Load(byte[] rawAssembly)`.

I wonder if there is an opposite operation like `byte[] Store(Assembly assembly)`. If not, how can I convert an assembly object to `byte[]` for calling `Assembly Load(byte[] rawAssembly)` totally in memory without writing the assembly to a file? Thanks!

Comment: The question comes from the situation that I am using a third-party library which returns an Assembly instance to me, and I must use reflection to call its methods. I don't know how the library creates this assembly object. I just wonder if I can store the assembly object to byte[] and reload it with 'Assembly Load(byte[] rawAssembly)'. Thanks!

Comment: The assembly you have in mind: where did it come from? Was it created in memory (AssemblyBuilder etc)? Or did it come from a file?

Comment: why not read the file as a binary stream?

Comment: This is a chicken-and-egg question.  If you have a byte[] that represents an assembly then storing it is never a problem.  FileStream can write it to a file, MemoryStream can store it to memory.  The egg problem is where the byte[] came from.  Completely creating it from scratch is not feasible without significant help from, say, Reflection.Emit.  You *always* use a file if you use System.CodeDom, even if you ask for memory only.

Answer (score 7):

System.Security.Policy.Hash is able to calculate a Hash regardless of the assembly's location. So we have at least 2 ways to obtain an assembly as a byte array:

1) Using reflection:

```
var hash = new Hash(assembly);
var dllAsArray = (byte[]) hash.GetType()
    .GetMethod("GetRawData", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .Invoke(hash, new object[0]);
```

2) Using a fake HashAlgorithm implementation:

```
public class GetWholeBodyPseudoHash : HashAlgorithm
{
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if(disposing) _memoryStream.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    static GetWholeBodyPseudoHash()
    {
        CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(GetWholeBodyPseudoHash), typeof(GetWholeBodyPseudoHash).FullName);
    }

    private MemoryStream _memoryStream=new MemoryStream();
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        _memoryStream.Dispose();
        _memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    }

    protected override void HashCore(byte[] array, int ibStart, int cbSize)
    {
        _memoryStream.Write(array, ibStart, cbSize);
    }

    protected override byte[] HashFinal()
    {
        return _memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}

...
var bytes = new Hash(yourAssembly).GenerateHash(new GetWholeBodyPseudoHash());
```

Answer (score 4):

To convert an assembly from AppDomain to byte[] use:

```
var pi = assembly.GetType().GetMethod("GetRawBytes", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
byte[] assemblyBytes = (byte[]) pi.Invoke(assembly, null);
```

Comment: Works all fine... Confimred on CodDom in-memory compiled asms.

Answer (score 3):

System.Reflection.Assembly implements ISerializable.  Create an instance of BinaryFormatter and call its Serialize method on any stream - MemoryStream, FileStream, etc.

```
Assembly yourAssembly;
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var ms = new MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(ms, yourAssembly);
var reloadedAssembly = Assembly.Load(ms.GetBuffer());
```

Comment: Note, this method didn't work for me, while the reflection method of @PlamenTotev did.