# How can I feed a loaded Assembly to a Roslyn Workspace in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am enhancing an existing process with runtime code generation. The code I am creating at runtime needs access to some of the same dlls that the process creating the code is already referencing.

Problem is that the process runs within some 3rd party software that loads dlls from resources and injects them into my process... thus I do not have access to either a dll on disk nor to the resource that contained the dll in the external wrapper.

As a result I am trying to use the assemblies I already have in memory and feed them into the Roslyn workspace into which I place my runtime code for compilation.
I thought I could try serializing the Assembly with a binary formatter as per this SO: 
[Opposite operation to Assembly Load(byte[] rawAssembly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883687/opposite-operation-to-assembly-loadbyte-rawassembly/16889549#16889549)

But even if I pretty much take the code as is:

```
Assembly yourAssembly = typeof(object).Assembly;
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
var ms = new MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(ms, yourAssembly);
var reloadedAssembly = Assembly.Load(ms.GetBuffer());
```

I get:

```
An exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
```

None of the other search results seemed any better.

What I want to do is something like:

```
var assemblyRef = MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly(typeof(object).Assembly);
mySolution.AddMetadataReference(projectId, assemblyRef);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you already have a reference to the assembly object somewhere, right? What happens when you pass that to `MetadataReference.CreateFromAssembly()`?

Comment: @Ties: That only works if it was loaded from a file.  http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/MetadataReference/MetadataReference.cs,324

Comment: @Ties: As per Slaks comment; if you look at his link the CreateFromAssembly() is a deprecated method that internally does:  
    string location = CorLightup.Desktop.GetAssemblyLocation(assembly);  
Then loads from file. So it's the same as running CreateFromFile().. ie doesn't work in my case. I just put it in there as an example of what I wish I had :)

Comment: Ah, right, sorry for that. I actually checked the code on `source.roslyn.io`, but overlooked the `Obsolete` attribute, and forgot all about it being deprecated (it used to work in the preview versions of Roslyn).

Answer (score 2):

For a managed assembly loaded using Assembly.Load(byte[]) you can create a Roslyn MetadataReference like so:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
var modulePtr = Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(assembly.ManifestModule);

var peReader = new PEReader((byte*)modulePtr, bytes.Length))
var metadataBlock = peReader.GetMetadata();
var moduleMetadata = ModuleMetadata.CreateFromMetadata((IntPtr)metadataBlock.Pointer, metadataBlock.Length);
var assemblyMetadata = AssemblyMetadata.Create(moduleMetadata);
var reference = assemblyMetadata.GetReference();
```

Note that this doesn't work for assemblies loaded from a file, since the layout in the memory is different.

Comment: Great solution for platform dependent code. Is there a possiblility doing the same using .NET Standard 2.0? I'm using roslyn in such a context.